# Will the input() function execution context be inside the check() function execution context?

Tags: javascript

My question is about the execution context in this code: when the function check() got called using the console.log will the input() function execution context be inside the check() function execution context  or outside of it .

```
var x;
var y;
function check(){
y = input()
  if(y<10){
    return "true";
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}

function input(){
  x = eval(prompt("please enter a number "));
  return x;
}

console.log(check());
```

I tried just to make the variable deceleration outside of the function and assign them inside the function.

The result that i got when i added input as (9) i got true and that is correct.the question is about the context only.

Comment: Psst.. hint. you don't need the eval prompt.  You [almost] never need eval at all.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher can i use parse-int() instead of the eval if the value that is going to be prompted is  number

Comment: In the long run you'll want to use something besides `prompt` -- but for learning, sure, use `prompt.`   If the person is entering an *integer* -- sure, use `parseInt`.  If the person is entering a *number* -- ie, a floating point number, use `parseFloat

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher i think the parse-float works for input integers and floating point its suitable for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not "inside". Execution contexts are one on top of the other on a stack.

You have the Global Execution Context at the bottom. When you call `check()`, its execution context is pushed on top of the stack.

```
check()
-------
Global
```

When inside `check` you call `input()`, the new execution context will be again pushed on top:

```
input()
-------
check()
-------
Global
```

When `input` returns a value, its context is popped out of the array, and execution of `check` resumes. When `check` returns, its context is popped out too.

Both functions have access to variables `x` and `y` through the scope chain.